# Failed to remount /tmp to RAM (tmpfs)

Tags: mount, tmpfs

I'm trying to mount `/tmp` to RAM on Ubuntu server (14.04):

```
echo "tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime 0 0" | tee -a /etc/fstab
```

This line seems to be fine, it's added to `/etc/fstab`, and after the system reboot `/tmp` is mounted as expected.

But when I try to apply this changes on the fly (without system reboot):

```
mount -o remount /tmp
```

I get this error: *not mounted or bad option*

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `mount` manpage:

`remount
Attempt to remount an already-mounted filesystem.  This is commonly used to change the mount flags for a filesystem,  especially  to  make  a  readonly  filesystem writeable. It does not change device or mount point.`

Since `/tmp` is not already mounted when you try `mount -o remount /tmp`, it fails. To make it work while it is not already mounted, you need to do `mount /tmp` instead.

Comment: (although this is not necessarily a good idea, e.g. if you use any software that uses sockets in `/tmp/.??*` like `/tmp/.X11-unix`, the original sockets will now be unreachable)

Comment: That's right. In that case safer to take the `nodev` option off

Comment: what does nodev option do? from manpage it's unclear. honestly, nosuid and nodev options just copied from somewhere.. both are unclear

Comment: nodev only affects device nodes, not sockets.  I mean if you do this on a running system, some of the files you're hiding in the overmounted /tmp might have been important